# Inject Doctrine Entity Manager to Zf2 Form

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I tried to inject doctrine entity manager in zf2 form in the way that is described here 
http://zf2cheatsheet.com/#doctrine (Inject the Entity Manager to Form) but it fails with error  _construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, null given...

Anybody solved this problem ?

Comment: Can you post your code please

Comment: Some code will help us to guide you

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways on how to do this. The dirty but easier way is to just give the form In your Controller Action The Entity Manager trough a param like so:

```
/**             
 * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
 */                
protected $em;

public function getEntityManager()
{
    if (null === $this->em) {
        $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    }
    return $this->em;
}

public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
...
public function yourAction() {
...
   $form = new YourForm($this->getEntityManger());
...
}
```

You then can just call entity Manager methods within your form:

```
public function __construct($em)
{
...
   $repository = $em->getRepository('\Namespace\Entity\Namespace');
...
}
```

The more complex but nicer way requires you to add the getServiceconfig function within your modules Module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'YourFormService' => function ($sm) {
                $form = new YourForm($sm);
                $form->setServiceManager($sm);
                return $form;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Within your Form you´ll need to implent the ServiceManagerAwareInterface and the setServiceManager setter.

```
use Zend\Form\Form as BaseForm;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;

class CategoryForm extends BaseForm implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{
protected $sm;

public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $sm)
{
    $this->sm = $sm;
}

public function __construct($sm)
{
...
$em = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
...
}
```

You then have to call your Form within your controller differently. The usual`$form = new YourForm();` constructor will not work with the factory we created.

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('YourFormService');
```

I usually use the dirty way to get the Entitymanager but as soon as I need the Service Locator I create a factory personally I dont think its worth it to create a big overhead with the services.

I hope this helped a bit.

Comment: Going with option 2 and just injecting the entity manager would be the best approach, it's not necessary to inject the whole service manager.

Comment: Thanks guys a lot for your answers! 
I tried the first method but it give me the error - "_construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, null given...". 
I will try the second method with serviceManager later (now i am little busy) and i will comment the result.

Comment: You don't have to setServiceLocator() manually on your object. If class is instanceof ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, you better register this service as invokable instead of factory. The service manager will inject ServiceLocator automatically.

Comment: @takeshin I did not have the chance to work with zf3 as of yet. If I do I'll definitely update this answer since it's tagged for zendframework, too.